# Operational amplifier design

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, integrated-circuit, cmos

[image]

Hello! Can you tell me the benefit of having the differential amplifier connected the way shown in the image. Also what's the purpose of devices in green circle and what's the benefit of placing it there?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to give an attribution to the source of the diagrams if they are not your own. It's site policy. It can also help provide context for the diagrams.

Comment: Don't place the same picture (with and without your red/green markings) twice as then I start to look for differences, which there aren't any! Only the picture with the markings is enough.

Comment: The part marked with red is the differential NMOS input pair with biasing, it is the opamp's input stage. If you do not "see" this then you need to step back and study the **differential pair**. The MOSFETs in the green area are the "cascodes" of the folded cascode structure. You should be familiar with the **cascode** already, if not, get studying!

Comment: I know it is the input pair, but what's the benefit of having to bias it that way? I know hat cascodes are again what advantage do they provide by placing it there?

Comment: Without folding the cascode, would you need a higher supply rail to get the required signal swing?

Answer (score 2):

The green FETS, 4 of them, allow rail_to_rail operation of the four nodes,

while (this is important)

preventing high voltage stresses on the rail_referenced FETs.

Comment: Which rail-referenced fets are you referring to?